# Sleep mode in Win7 doesn't work any more (shuts down PC somehow, and taking very long to load system again), battery defect?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, energy-saving

**UPDATE:**
So, i figured out that i behaves like i remove battery when sleeping. Like it has no power connection, how could that be?

**OLD POST:**
I'm not sure what is wrong, but after putting in "sleep-mode", my pc normally starts within seconds, not showing bootscreen and not asking for OS.

But somehow every time is start "sleep-mode" my pc starts booting again. The only thing i know is that after selecting OS (which i m usually not asked when slept) Windows takes so long to start. After logged in it takes some while to react again. It's like it is loosing power connection or something like that...

I hope you understood what i mean. It takes much longer than it normally does, and even hibernate is faster.
Could it be there is something wrong with battery or what else could be the reason?

Comment: I think it goes to hibernation, not shutdown. Can you confirm?

Comment: I didn't choose hibernation, i choosed this sleep-mode (if this the correct term in english, but i think so). Hibernation works well if chosse that, but i used the mode where everything stays in RAM, and this should be sleep-mode, isn't it?

Comment: Windows automatically goes to hibernation after some time in sleep to conserve power. Tell me this. When you switch on your PC again and login, do u see it exactly the way u left it before sleep?

Comment: Yeah, ok. In earlier this happened after few hours (switching to hibernate), but you heard it starting and shutting down again. But now it is directly after started sleeping.

Comment: So, i tested it twice. After sleeping, everything is the same including cursor position. But it takes so long to load everything, and the browser hangs for a fes minutes. After hibernating, it works much faster than in sleep mode, but still everything is there, including the cursor.

Comment: So, i figured out that i behaves like i remove battery when sleeping. Like it has no power connection, how could that be?

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my computer is is finally back from waranty services and they replaced some internal parts (which i amg oing to find out what) and now it works.  So it was caused by some hadware defect. Thanks again for you help and answers.

Comment: After all, were you able to find out what parts did they replace?